# Get all Windows 8/10 toast notifications

Tags: c#, notifications, toast, windows-10

Is it possible to get notified when other apps raise Windows 8/10 toast notifications and get the content of these toasts? Or, is there a way to get all of the current notifications so that I can poll this list for additions?

WinRT's `Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager` has a [`CreateToastNotifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208645.aspx) method which can take an application id and returns a `ToastNotifier` bound to a specific app. Theoretically, it seems that creating a `ToastNotifier` for each running app (if this is not prevented for security reasons) and calling [`GetScheduledToastNotifications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.getscheduledtoastnotifications.aspx) periodically could get scheduled notifications, but not other types of notifications.

There doesn't seem to be an easy-to-find API for this. With Windows 10's new notification center, are there any new ways to access notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a supported way to do this on current OSes (Windows 8, 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1). An app can only see its own notifications.

CreateToastNotifier only works for apps in the calling package. It cannot be called for arbitrary other apps. Windows Phone 8.1's Action Centre API is similarly limited to the current app (see [Managing toast notifications in action center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn631259(v=win.10).aspx))

Information on Windows 10 specific API hasn't yet been announced.